# Can't take difference of two sums

Tags: summation

I am taking difference between two sums.

[image]

Of course, what I wanted is A_s

But it's not evaluating this.

I tried Simplify, FullSimplify, Expand, and so on. But nothing works. What should I do?

---

I tried Nasser's suggestion. It is great! However, it works when I write it as you did, but it doesn't work when I write it as visually easy-to-read equation. Why is it like this?

[image]

Comment: as far as I know, Mathematica does not simplify sums with symbolic index. But maybe someone knows better. You could always use this trick `((Sum[a[t], {t, 1, s}] - Sum[a[t], {t, 1, s - 1}]) /. s -> 10) /. 
 10 -> s` and this gives `a[s]`

Comment: @Nasser Thank you!. Just one thing that's going strange. It works when I write it as you did, but it doesn't work when I write it as visually easy-to-read equation. I edited my question to show what I mean.

Comment: I think may be you have syntax error. If you post plain Mathematica code it will be easier.   The "/." is the `ReplaceAll` command. Make sure it is the same in your 2D illustration.

Comment: You need a space between the "." and the "1" to avoid it being interpreted as "0.1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 rule1 = Sum[a_.[t], {t, 1, m_}] - Sum[a_.[t], {t, 1, m_ - k_.}] :> 
   Sum[a[t], {t, m - k + 1, m}];
```

and then:

```
(Sum[a[t], {t, 1, s}] - Sum[a[t], {t, 1, s - 1}]) /. rule1

(*  a[s]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Wow this is a magic. Thank you so much. But what is ":>" ?? I googled but couldn't find it. Can you show me some mathematica documentation for ":>" ? Looks so useful.

Comment: @ user42459 Type `?:>` in a notebook and evaluate. You will get an answer. Click then over the chevron `>>` in the end of this answer and you will have more details and examples.

Comment: @user42459 check this: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html